# Android: Clear keyboard input when edittext is cleared

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-keypad

I want to set an automatic thousand separator to my edittext.
I did it with an textwatcher. In

```
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
```

i save the current value of my edittext, format it with

```
@Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            InputField.this.removeTextChangedListener(this);
            double tmp = getDoubleValue();

            s.clear();
s.append(DecimalFormat.getInstance(Locale.GERMAN).format(tmp));

            InputField.this.addTextChangedListener(this);
        }

    });
```

But the Keyboard from my Galaxy Tab doesn't care If I clear the editable. It keeps the current input and fills the edittext with the complete number. A short example:

I type "1", the keyboard inserts "1", the edittext shows "1".
I type  "2", the keyboard inserts "12", the edittext shows "112"
I type "3", the keyboard inserts "123", the edittext shows "112.123"
I press the delete button, the keyboard inserts "12", the edittext shows "11.212.312"
I press the delete button again, the keyboard inserts "1", the edittext shows "112.123.121"

My question is:
how can I disable this keyboardfeature?[image]

or how can I clean this keyboard "cache"?

If I use inputtype "numberDecimal", it works but I can't use points as thousand separators(but it is needed in germany), because they will be interpreted as decimal mark and there can only be one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if you can clean the cache, but how about disabling the suggestion bar.. you can do that programatically:

```
YourEditText.setInputType(YourEditText.getInputType()
| EditorInfo.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS
| EditorInfo.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_FILTER);
```

or you can deactivate in your `EditText` XML tag.. you can set:

```
<EditText>
   android:inputType="textFilter
   .... />
```

you can use this value too but unfortunately it doesn't work in all devices specially HTC

```
android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
```

**Edit**

Sometimes it doesn't work because it's up to the implementation of the keyboard to do the right thing including the Flags.. However, everything has a workaround can you try the following code in XML:

```
android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|textVisiblePassword"
```

or in Java:

```
yourEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD);
```

and give me a feedback if it worked or not..

Comment: I tried it, but it has no effect, I use Samsung Galaxy Tab 2

Comment: the suggestion bar is still showing? or it is not showing yet the problem remains?

Comment: the suggestion bar is still showing. I tried it with noSuggestions, textfilter, visiblePassword in xml and code

Comment: Thank you very much, InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD works for me :)